# Replace all occurrences of a String in all columns in a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 20 Columns and in these columns there is a value XX which i want to replace with Empty String. How do i achieve that in scala. The withColumn function is for a single column, But i want to pass all 20 columns and replace values that have XX in the entire frame with Empty String , Can some one suggest a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can gather all the `stringType` columns in a list and use `foldLeft` to apply your `removeXX` UDF to each of the columns as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "aaXX", "bb"),
  (2, "ccXX", "XXdd"),
  (3, "ee", "fXXf")
).toDF("id", "desc1", "desc2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val stringColumns = df.schema.fields.collect{
  case StructField(name, StringType, _, _) => name
}

val removeXX = udf( (s: String) =>     
  if (s == null) null else s.replaceAll("XX", "")
)

val dfResult = stringColumns.foldLeft( df )( (acc, c) =>
  acc.withColumn( c, removeXX(df(c)) )
)

dfResult.show
+---+-----+-----+
| id|desc1|desc2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   aa|   bb|
|  2|   cc|   dd|
|  3|   ee|   ff|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Another way to get StringColumns is testDF.dtypes.filter (_._2 == "StringType").map (_._1)

Answer (score 0):

```
def clearValueContains(dataFrame: DataFrame,token :String,columnsToBeUpdated : List[String])={
  columnsToBeUpdated.foldLeft(dataFrame){
    (dataset ,columnName) =>
      dataset.withColumn(columnName, when(col(columnName).contains(token), "").otherwise(col(columnName)))
  }
}
```

You can use this function .. where you can put **token** as "XX" . Also the columnsToBeUpdated is the **list of columns** in which you need to search for the particular column.

```
dataset.withColumn(columnName, when(col(columnName) === token, "").otherwise(col(columnName)))
```

you can use the above code to replace on **exact match**.

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this as well in scala.

```
//Getting all columns
val columns: Seq[String] = df.columns
//Using DataFrameNaFunctions to achieve this.
val changedDF = df.na.replace(columns, Map("XX"-> ""))
```

Hope this helps.